# Strange behavior ob_start. Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, ob-start

Firstly I'm sorry for my bad english.
So on localhost all well and good, but on web server displays incomprehensible numbers with symbols, for example `326e`.

It seems to have found a problem spot .. only what the problem is I can not understand ..
The problem arises in the method `init`, which is called in `bootstrap.php` -> `Kohana::init`, this method is in the file `\system\classes\Kohana\Core.php`

All my fault line

```
// Start an output buffer
ob_start();
```

If you write `echo ' ';`  before this line, these strange characters will not be displayed if you write `echo 'test'` will be displayed on the screen only the word `test`
If echo 'test' write buffer after the start then you will see a "strange_symbols test" ..
Anybody have any idea what is that?

Comment: Problem solved with this bug report http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4661

Comment: Put it as an answer and accept it so it's clear for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with this bug report dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4661